# alternate row value minus SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Guys I have a data set from my query that looks like this:

```
Date   |  Count   | Activity
10 Nov |    10    |    A
11 Nov |    11    |    A
10 Nov |    12    |    B
11 Nov |    13    |    B
```

I am trying to achieve this result. Basically the logic is the 2nd row will minus the 1st row, 4th row minus the 3rd row.

```
Date   |  Count   | Activity  | Diff
10 Nov |    10    |    A      |  0
11 Nov |    11    |    A      |  1
10 Nov |    12    |    B      |  0
11 Nov |    13    |    B      |  1
```

My current query looks like this:

```
select  DATE, count(distinct(ID)) as Count,
count(distinct(ID)) - LAG(count(distinct(ID)),1) over (order by count(distinct(ID))) as Eng_change
from (Select DATA.*,PRODUCT.MAPPING from DATA left join PRODUCT on DATA.Part_Number=PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NUMBER ) OVERALLFUNNEL 
WHERE ACTIVITY_RANK>5
group by OVERALLFUNNEL.ACTIVITY,OVERALLFUNNEL.DATE
ORDER BY ACTIVITY_RANK ASC
```

Using lag will give minus always the previous row but that's not what I want.

Any help or function?

regards

Comment: Am using oracle

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want the difference within each activity.  If so:

```
select DATE, activity,
       count(distinct ID) as Count,
       (count(distinct ID) -
        LAG(count(distinct ID), 1) over (partition by activity
                                         order by count(distinct ID)
                                        )
      ) as Eng_change
```

This will give `NULL` for the first value.  If you want `0`, use `coalesce()` or something similar.